# Mathematical relationship between radius (meters) and the zoom level of the map

Tags: zoom, mapbox-gl-js

I've created an HeatMap (using Mapbox GL) and I want to achieve a behaviour similar to Snapchat, I mean every time you press on shape you get the coordinates of your tap and from here I want to get all items inside a specific radius.

```
MIN ZOOM = 1
MAX ZOOM = 22
R = radius of the circle that have center in the position get from the user tap.
Z = the current zoom of the map.
```

Now the problem is that, if I say R=1Km and Z=16 and I press inside the HeatCircle I get all the items, but when the zoom changes I need to change the radius itself, if it were not so I would have Z=10 and R=1Km which will not retrieve items, cause the small radius.
It's a bit complicated to explain, but if you're familiar with Snapchat, you'll get it.

[image: An image that describe what I mean]

What I'm asking is the what relations does exist between radius of HeatCircle and map Zoom?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most sensible way to begin addressing this is to examine the relative area encompassed by the tap with respect to the area shown in the view extent. Let's define it as

```
r = A_tap/A_extent
```

Ideally, if you keep `r` constant for all view extents, you should be able to get the area of any tap given the total viewable extent. Moreover, if you assume the tap is circular, you can get the diameter.

So I would select one zoom extent, define a "reasonable" diameter to use for each tap (in your example above, Z16 = 1KM), and calculate `r`. You can then repeat this process backwards every time the zoom extent changes.